# How to track requests and completion status in async systems?

Tags: architecture, distributed-system, system-design

I am trying to explore solutions to track requests in Async systems. This is my use case:

- Currently in our system we have 2 services communicating asynchronously with `Service 1` sending an operation to be performed against n items to `Service 2`.
- `Service 2` on completion of those operations sends response back to `Service 1`.

Currently how tracking is handled is via a request tracker table in `Service 1`'s DB from which we keep removing entries as and when we get response from `Service 2`.

I was thinking if there is a more generic open source solution which I can leverage to track pending operations and perform some action once all pending are completed.

Anyone had a similar use case before?

Comment: Are you looking for some out-of-the-box solution? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want to explore an out-of-box solution wherein I can do away with tracking requests on my own using my tracker tables in db and have a library/service take care of it

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic on SO. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project which solves the problem of long-running requests as well as many service orchestration use cases. In your example, the request to service1 can be modeled as a single blocking function call independent of the duration of the request processing (can be months).